# Dialog-flow v2 using rest api in angular 6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

How to use the dialogflow v2 using rest api method in angular. I've gone through the documentation I didn't understand it properly. Can someone explain to me how to use that?

Comment: This question doens't comply with StackOverflow's standard for a good question.  Please update your question after it meets these requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The Dialogflow API sits at the HTTP request / response layer, so your choice of front end frameworks shouldn't affect its behavior.

If you're looking for practice with Dialogflow's API, check out these two Google codelabs:

Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 1)
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2)
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#0

I hope that helps!